# Stepper motor model

Tags: dymola

Good morning,
 I'm doing my internship using modelica and I tried to model a stepper motor in Dymola but unfortunately it does not work, please can you help me to find in modelica librairies a stepper motor model which I can use it in my project.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try reading [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For understanding how to ask a well, understandable and structured question.

Comment: Some Modelica libraries are hosted on github, you can search for a specific language: https://github.com/search?l=Modelica&q=motor&type=Code